# Angular 6, Routing not working after deployment user http-server

Tags: node.js, httpserver, angular6, angular-routerlink

I have a sample web application with two page. by default it will load login screen. When a user click activation mail, it will go to register page. Its working fine locally using `ng serve`. I published using`ng-build` and hosted using `http-server` page its going to login screen. But if i click activation link from mail, its not going to register page and its error